# Kendo grid input control value gets cleared on click of add row method

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

im having a kendo grid with add and delete button on each row.Each row has a html input control.when i add some value to input control and click on add button value gets cleared.
How to save the each input control value?

```
<script id="ob-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input id="tree"/>
</script>
<script>
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [

                { field: "DispalyName", title: "DispalyName" },
                { field: "Value", title: "Value", template: $("#ob-template").html() },
                {
                    command: [
                         { title: "create", template: "<img class='ob-image'    src='../DefaultAssets/Images/New.png' style='padding: 0 8px 0 8px;' />" },
                         { title: "up", template: "<img class ='up-image' src='../DefaultAssets/Images/UpArrow.png' style='padding: 0 8px 0 8px;' />" },
                         { title: "down", template: "<img class ='down-image' src='../DefaultAssets/Images/DownArrow.png' style='padding: 0 8px 0 8px;' />" },
                         { title: "delete", template: "<img class ='delete-image' src='../DefaultAssets/Images/Delete.png' style='padding: 0 8px 0 8px;' />" }],
                }
            ]

$("#grid").on("click", ".ob-image", function (e) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");               
            grid.addRow();            
        });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid" style="float: left;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to insert a new value if you want to add a row.
maybe like:

```
var datasource = grid.dataSource;
var newRecord = { DispalyName: "8164", Value: "147"}
datasource.insert(newRecord);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i want to insert "Value" field .Value field should be empty when i click on add button,if i type some values to the field it should get added to the input control.